# Prove a large number of samplings converge to a set of small number of samples

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, sampling-theory

I don't know how to start with this problem.

---

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for the comments from @BruceET and @felipeh, I update the problem as follows:

In a $k$-dimensional space, given a set of $n$ points: $X=\{x_1, x_2,..., x_n\}$ which is sampled from an known distribution $P$. Given a set of $m$ points ($m << n$): $Y=\{y_1,y_2,...,y_m\}$ which is also drawn from $P$. Suppose $\{z_1, z_2,...,z_m\} \subset X$ are the closest points (in term of Euclidean distance) of $\{y_1,y_2,...,y_m\}$ respectively. A gap $g$ is defined as follows:

$g = max\{|z_1 - y_1|^2, |z_2 - y_2|^2,..., |z_m - y_m|^2\}$

where $|a-b|^2$ denotes the Euclidean distance between a, b.

Prove that if $m$ is fixed, $g \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

---

Thanks @Henry for the comment, I prove it as follows, could you please check whether it is correct? I do it in a uniform distribution.

Suppose $g = max\{|z_1 - y_1|^2, |z_2 - y_2|^2,..., |z_m - y_m|^2\} = \| z - y \|_{max}$.

For any $\varepsilon > 0$, put a hypersphere radius  $\varepsilon$ around $y$ such that $y$ is the centroid. (*)

Suppose there is no sample of $X$ exists in the hypersphere as $n \rightarrow \infty$. (**)

We cut the space by a line $d$ through $y$. Then, we project samples of $X$, which distance to $d$ is less than $\delta$ ($0 < \delta \leq \varepsilon$), on $d$ and denote these projected samples as $x_d$. Suppose the boundary of $d$ is $[a, b]$, i.e. $a \leq x_d \leq b$. According to the law of large numbers theorem, $\overline{x_d}$ (the average of samples projected on $d$) $\rightarrow (a + b)/2$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Now if there is no sample in the hypersphere:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    \overline{x_d} \rightarrow \int_a^b \mathrm{\frac{x}{b-a}}\,\mathrm{d}x = \int_a^{y_d - \delta} \mathrm{\frac{x}{b-a}}\,\mathrm{d}x + \int_{y_d + \delta}^b \mathrm{\frac{x}{b-a}}\,\mathrm{d}x \\
    = \frac{a+b}{2} - \frac{2\delta y_d}{b - a} \neq \frac{a + b}{2}
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
The above equation conflicts the law of large numbers theorem, this indicates that (**) is false; so there exists at least one sample in the hyperphere. This statement accompanies with (*) indicate that $g = \| z - y \|_{max} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Do you know that $P$ is a discrete distribution?  If not, isn't this going to be false because the event of drawing exactly the same sample twice can be zero?  Perhaps I don't understand the question.

Comment: Are you sure the statement to be proved is correctly stated?

Comment: @BruceEt: No. I am not sure. My problem is: if I have some data points (m points) in a bounded area. I want to sample in that area as much as possible to see whether the sampling contain my m points (or at least close to my m points).

Comment: @felipeh: P is a continuous distribution. The problem is in an ideal case as n = Infinity, is it possible that X contains Y or X contains points that are very close to Y.

Comment: What is _very close?_ Suppose my experiment is to sample 100 obs at random from UNIF(0,1) and find the biggest gap btw observations. I do it 100,000 times. By simulation, the mean of the max gaps is .051.

Comment: @BruceET: Thanks, can we prove that as the number of samplings $n \rightarrow \infty$, the max gaps $\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: Convergence in probability will be surprisingly slow for large $k$.  But it will happen eventually: for any $\delta,\epsilon > 0$, (a) choose the $\{y_1,y_2,...,y_m\}$ first;  (b) put a hypersphere radius $\epsilon$ around each one; then (c) you can choose $n$ large enough so the probability that all the hyperspheres will contain at least one of  $\{x_1, x_2,..., x_n\}$  is greater than $1-\delta$.